# How to search for [ character using generic sql query?

Tags: sql

I have a string column in a table that has [ and ] characters. I want to search them using a SQL query. I tried using queries

```
SELECT * from EM_TAGS WHERE TAG like '%[%';
SELECT * from EM_TAGS WHERE TAG like '%[[%';
SELECT * from EM_TAGS WHERE TAG like '%\[%';
```

But none of them return any rows although they are there. What is correct query. It has to be generic since this database is to be ported to all major databases like Oracle, MySQL etc.

Comment: `[` and `]` in like patterns is no problem - as long as you stay away from SQL Server. And the escape character solution below doesn't work on Oracle, _ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `ESCAPE` with your `like` statement. for example :

```
SELECT * from EM_TAGS WHERE TAG LIKE '%\\[%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

and probably you are looking for this that looks for string that has opening and closing brackets like '%[%]%':

```
SELECT * from EM_TAGS WHERE TAG LIKE '%\\[%\\]%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

Comment: this worked
SELECT * from EM_TAGS WHERE TAG LIKE '%\\[%' ESCAPE '\'

Comment: I get an error trying to execute this. Which dbms is this for?

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server. actually you need to put single \ instead of \\